# How to save file using Azure/Web API to folder on shared network drive

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

Currently trying to save a file to a folder on a network location.

`network//location//folder/save-here`

The WebAPI is connected though azure/VPN /Entity Framework, however I need to save the file on the protected network location, not just a record in the database.
I've started trying to use a Hybrid Connection, however I'm not sure it will help solve this issue.

What is the best way to achieve saving a file to a folder on a network location from a Web API/Azure?

Comment: Is your API using the Application Service Plan or is it on a VM?

Comment: Application Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in the Application Service Plan you cannot mount a file share.

If you were using Azure's file share from Azure Storage, you could just save the file using the API. However, since you are trying to save to an on-prem file share, you might need to set up some kind of service (possibly another API) running on-prem than you would call and it would be able to save the file for you.

Comment: File share from Azure Storage is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much for the suggestion!